# Proper label type assignment while working with LightGBM package in python

Tags: python, label, valueerror, lightgbm

I am trying to work with LightGBM package in Python and encountered this error:

"TypeError: Wrong type(ndarray) for label, should be list or numpy array".

My target(label) is created as: y_train.values and is an array which has characteristics like:

```
Type: int64,
Size: (1000,1)
Value: array([[0],
              [0],
...)
```

When I traced back this error,I found this code @
[Basic.py code of lightgbm package](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/lightgbm/basic.py):

Function list_to_1d_numpy is throwing this error.

I couldn't find any reason though why this function should throw error. However
it is calling one function is_numpy_1d_array which checks for condition

`len(data.shape) == 1, however when i do len(y_train.shape)` it says 2.

Any ideas how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was thinking in right direction. The label(y_train) needs to be a one dimensional array. I changed it to one dimensional by using:

```
y=y_train.ravel()
```

and it worked!

However while creating the target itself, we could have had

```
y_train=dataframe['target'].values
I had it like: dataframe[['target']].values,
```

which created 2 dimensional arrays